# SQL CE Editor - please help me find one

Tags: sql-server-ce

I need SQL CE database editor with visual representation of relations and tables in database.
[This one](http://sqlcedatabaseeditor.codeplex.com/) does not work. It crashes at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Web Developer Express SP1? Or http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com ?
I have a list of thrid arty tools here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

**Compact Query** does the job brilliantly.